# Alternating row color for JasperReports

Tags: colors, jasper-reports, rows, alternate

I want to get color to alternate for the rows in a JasperReports subreport. I have all rows with the same background color but I want it to alternate. Can this be done?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes you can [set up a style](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/#conditionalstyles) inside the JRXML file like this:

```xml
<style name="Zebra" mode="Transparent">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 1]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#CAC5BB"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

and add it to your report elements like this:

```
<reportElement style="Zebra" mode="Opaque" x="1" y="1" width="554" height="20"/>
```

You cannot add conditional styles to style template files (e.g., `.jrtx` files).

Comment: this wont work if the column gets extended to the next page.

Answer (score 9):

If you are not using "styles", you can have a static text field (with no text) or a rectangle with the background color that you need, overlapping the textfield with data and set the printWhenExpression to `$V{report_COUNT}%2 == 1` OR `$V{report_COUNT}%2 == 0`