# Add color to last row of table in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

Good day

Im generating a jasper report using Java. Its generating properly with a table. The table is populated with list which I pass in map parameters.

I got a new requirement, I want to add color only to the last row of the table in it.

Tried with a lot of googling but still no use. Any ideas on it?

Comment: This post helps to find the last row: [Get first letter of first and last row in Jasper Reports table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34010529/876298) and this post about applying conditional style: [Alternating row color for JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8980439/876298)

Comment: @AlexK, Thanks for the links. I wanted to add color only to the last row. Do you have any idea on conditional style?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in functionality for that.

But you could use two tables. Have the first one display everything but the last row and the second one display only the last row. Place them directly above each other, the second one should be floating to remain it's position at the bottom when the first one stretches.

Pass two maps from your Java class; Split your original map into two maps (one with everything but the last, other with only the last row) and pass each map as a parameter for the Dataset of the corresponding table.

Comment: but the case is I'm passing a list to the report. How to handle this one?

Comment: Oh then I misunderstood your "list which I pass in map parameters" as parameters defined as maps which contained lists.
However, you can do the same thing with lists basically.

Comment: I didnt test the code today. But when I put the static field just below the table. It keeps there at the same place even when the table has full data. Which means its mixing with the table

Comment: That's why you have to set it's position type as "float". this will ensure the right positioning relative to the table.

Comment: OK. So, second table should be set with position float.. Will let u know tomorrow. :) or it would be really good if we can write a conditional custom style.. any idea?

Comment: I came to know that we can write conditional custom style. But I dont know how to write it for table row. by checking the td value with a particular text :(

Comment: It doesnt work even if I put float also to the new table. Its fixed at the same place